# New images not showing since upgrade to laravel 9

Tags: laravel, storage

Please help me. I upgraded from laravel 7 to 9

Previous images displays but newly uploaded images are not. Images are saved correctly in the **app/public/uploads** and generated link is i.e my-domain-name.com/uploads/0000/1/2022/12/06/img-x-150 is correct. When link is entered on browser it aborts to 404 error page. I have read articles that suggest I cleared the cache, delete the storage link folder in app/public and run:

`php artisan storage:link`

Which I have done with no success.

Comment: @Ron van der Heijden Please see my edited post thank you.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?